# Can I use the native android camera in phonegap over an iframe and send pictures on my webserver?

Tags: php, android, jquery, iframe, phonegap-build

I am building an app and because of my missing knowledge of java and Xcode I decided to make this app in HTML,PHP,CSS & javascript(jquery). Now I'm facing the problem of getting this app to the different devices and I want to use PhoneGap for that. I placed an index.html inside the server for the app and there is an iframe placed inside and nothing more. Is it still possible for me to get access to the media storage and send PHPdata back and forth while having an iframe as a bridge between PhoneGap on android and my website on its web server? Can I access the camera of the device?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: No, and you shouldn't try that.

The long answer (And the safer one) is to use `postMessage` as described in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), do it in a different way could cause inconsistency between devices (Remember how fragmented is android and how painful could be the backward compatibility with 4.3 and below)

So, you could get the iFrame element and then post a message like

`otherWindow.postMessage(InfoToSend, "*");`

In the same way, you could listen to that event inside the frame:

`window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);`

This will no cause cross-frame issues and it will be the safer way to pass information between the frames, this work in both directions, so you could ask (From inside your iFrame) to use some native feature (plugin), listen to this event in your device main app, executed what you need and after that send a postMessage (from your app) to your iFrame with the result (a `base64` img for example)

If you are trying to pass the `window.cordova` the instance or something similar, it won't work, so you will need to establish a conversation between the `iFrame` and the `window.top` frame.

Comment: A dream comes true :D So I can programm my webapp with php and javascript, html and css and have a index.html file with an iframe in the PhoneGap app in the www directory and when needed call the function to use camera and upload content? And is this secure? Please be true. Question is why there is no one on youtube or elsewhere who uses this technique and explains it?! Everyone could programm html css php and javascript with no need of making a nativ app anymore :0 @jjdltc

Comment: No one using this because is not the best option, @Zoung You could instead, have a REST api (Your php) and use Phonegap / Cordova as framework in your app (Cordova allow you to develop your app as a web), BTW everyone can program in Javascript/HTML/ccs to make mobile apps (Cordova / Phonegap)
Using an iFrame, push you to make a conversation between your App (Cordova) and your Web (iFrame), that's in my opinion a hard way. To use the camera, you should
> Trigger a msg from the iFrame
> Listen in your app (Cordova) 
> Use the native plugin (Cordova)
> Response to the iFrame with the result

Comment: so i should put my webapp in phonegap(.html style) and have this api on my webserver which is somehow connected to my phonegap app or how does this REST api work? :) @jjdltc PS how do i call on this api when php is not working inside phonegap?